# Running a ASP.Net MVC Application on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, asp.net-mvc

I have just installed a ASP.Net Mvc application on a windows server 2008.

When I try to use the application I see that IIS 7 tries to use the static file handler, I therefore get a 403 or 404 error.

I have tried adding the URL routing module and giving it priority.

I have install the ASP.Net MVC msi.

How do I get it to use the MVC handler?

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious...  You have installed the MVC framework on your server, yes?

Comment: Are you hosting it under a classic or integrated pipeline worker process?  Integrated should work out of the box for MVC apps.

Comment: Also, MVC v1 or MVC v2?

Comment: It is MVC v1 with integrated pipeline

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Server Manager, select Web Server (IIS) and press 'Add Role Services'. From here, select 'ASP.NET' and press OK to add the other required role services.